# Javax validation Constraints- Compare two Dates

Tags: java, validation, date, gwt, javabeans

I'm trying to setup a `javax` Validation to compare two dates with each other.
One date should be less than the other.

Also, I created a custom constraint for both of my dates. But the problem is, that my annotation interface can't handle with non-primitive data types.

Here is my Code: (I know that this is wrong, but maybe you can understand my problem if I show my source)

Bean:

```
@DateValidator(firstDate="assignmentStart", secondDate="assignmentEnd")
public class ProjectAssignment implements IsSerializable {

   private String id;
   private Project project;
   private String projectResponsibility;

   private Date assignmentStart;
   private Date assignmentEnd;
}
```

Annotation-Interface:

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateValidatorImpl.class)
public @interface DateValidator {

String firstDate();
String secondDate();

String message() default "";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};


}
```

So here is one Problem: I try to put the `Date` type into the `String` type.
But if I declare my `firstDate` and `secondDate` as a `Date`, there is an issue:

```
Invalid type Date for the annotation attribute `DateValidator.firstDate; 
only primitive type, `String`, `Class`, annotation, enumeration are permitted 
or 1-dimensional arrays thereof
```

Are there any other ways to compare 2 Dates with each other?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Java annotations can't accept `Date` fields, you will need to use `String` class.

You can convert a `Date` to a `String` with `DateFormat`, and then convert it back with the same `DateFormat`.

However, it implies that your assignment fields in `ProjectAssignment` must be of `String` type.